# Does Mac OS X allow for the creation of iso files and if so can they then be run on a virtual drive?

Tags: macos

Does Mac OS X allow for the creation of iso files (similar to that of Windows) and if so can they then be run on a virtual drive within the operating system ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? What do you want to run? Or do you just want to mount the images?

Comment: In windows u can convert programs to iso files to free up hard drive space which can then be run (mounted) via a virtual clone drive ? I'm not trying to do it at the moment just wondered if it can be achieved. I was thinking that equivalent of an iso file on a mac is a dmg image ?

Comment: @Simon - in that case why not just put the app onto another drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual format for this on OS X is a disk image (aka .dmg). To create them you can use Disk Utility.app (in /Appications/Utilities):

- insert the DVD you want to create the image from
- start Disk Utility
- select "New Image" from the toolbar and pick the DVD as a source. The .dmg can be stored wherever you want to

To open/use it afterwards, just doubleclick it in Finder.